# How do I locate dom elements within nested shadow doms using cypress when `find(...).shadow` is not a function`

Tags: cypress, integration-testing, web-component

I am working with Cypress v9.6.1 and custom elements with shadow dom.  We have several custom elements which are deeply nested - I am able to query for an input that is deeply nested with several web components successfully with something like this:

```
// WORKS!
cy.get(‘custom-element-1’)
    .shadow()
    .find('custom-element-2’)
    .shadow()
    .find('custom-element-3’)
    .shadow()
    .find(`custom-element-4[id=“ce”4]`)
    .shadow()
    .find('input');
```

What I'd like to do is determine the presence of that input before moving forward in the test.

```
Pseudo code - 
if (cy.('.deeply-nested-element').exists() ){
  do.not.click(button-a)
} else {
  click(button-a)
}
```

Following the cypress docs for [conditional testing -> element presence](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing#Element-existence) I attempted to express the above in a conditional and use on the `length` attribute to determine presence

```
//DOES NOT WORK
cy.get(‘custom-element-1').then(($ce) => {
    if($ce.shadow()
    .find('custom-element-2’)
    .shadow()
    .find('custom-element-3’)
    .shadow()
    .find(`custom-element-4[id=“ce”4]`)
    .shadow()
    .find('input')) // then do something
}
```

This gave me an error. `Property 'shadow' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'. Did you mean 'show'?ts(2551)`

Ignoring the ts error resulted in cypress test failing with:
`$ce.find(...).shadow is not a function`

I switched it up a little by chaining off of  shadow() with the same result

```
//ALSO DOES NOT WORK
cy.get(‘custom-element-1').shadow().then(($ceshadow) => {
    $ce
    .find('custom-element-2’)
    .shadow()
    .find('custom-element-3’)
    .shadow()
    .find(`custom-element-4[id=“ce”4]`)
    .shadow()
    .find('input');
}
```

And for this one:
`$ce.find(...).shadow is not a function`

It looks to me like the promise off of the `get` method does not pass to the callback an element with a shadow dom (JQuery).  The small problem I'm trying to figure out is a workaround to that.  The larger problem is how to set up a conditional that is determined by the presence of an element that is deeply nested within custom element shadow doms.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The `.shadow()` command is a Cypress command, but `$ce` is a jQuery object that can't call Cypress commands directly.

`$ce.find(...).shadow is not a function` occurs because both jQuery and Cypress have `.find()`, but only Cypress has `.shadow()`.

By making `includeShadowDom:true` global either in config or the test options, Cypress commands can be used without needing to chain `.shadow()` at every step.

If it's `custom-element-1` that is conditional, this should work

```js
it('tests deeply-nested shadow elements', {includeShadowDom:true}, () => {

  cy.get('body').then($body => {

    const ce1 = $body.find('custom-element-1');
    if (ce1.length) {

      cy.wrap(ce1)                 // wrap jQuery element into Cypress result
                                   // so that includeShadowDom:true is effective
        .find('custom-element-2')
        .find('custom-element-3')
        .find('custom-element-4[id="ce4"]')
        .find('input')) 
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Hmm - this didn't quite work b/c if it can't find ce1 cypress times out - I get an error Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element...

Comment: It looks like you're not applying the `find()` in jQuery (see note about `.find()` is available in both jQuery and Cypress). If you use the jQuery version as above, there is no timeout or test failure. The result of `$body.find('custom-element-1')` is an object with `length` 0 or 1.